# clf.fit(X, Y) Scikit learn 790 scikit learn in fit 236. ValueError: Number of labels=44 does not match number of samples=45

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Can't tell if it's from my code or whether it's a bug in the framework. 
Ok so I am just doing a personal side project for personal use to get better at python. This is my first project with over 100 lines of code ,so I am bound to have a error ,but I keep getting this error. When I get to the reference just in case I have a big syntax error I couldn't really see a difference. It points to errors inside the library
and the code ,so I am trying to figure out if there is a fix or not. The thing is over 100 lines of Code so I will try my best to put a simplified version. I would be grateful if you can help me learn what I did wrong inside.

```
from sklearn import tree

import pandas as pd

#to read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('aapl.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

#sets up the Decision tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

#input data for training ... there is a lot of data so this is 
#the smaller version to get to the point
X = [[7, 1, 17], [7, 3, 17], [7, 5, 17], [7, 7, 17], [7, 10, 17],
    [7, 11, 17], [7, 13, 17], [7, 15, 17], [7, 17, 17], [7, 19, 17]]

#Output data... This is only a fraction ,but it is simplified like X

Y = ['144.88,  145.30,  143.10,  143.50,  14277848',

     '144.88,  145.30,  143.10,  143.50,  14277848',

     '143.69,  144.79,  142.72,  144.09,  21569557',

     '142.90, 144.75,  142.90,  144.18,  19201712',

     '144.11,  145.95,  143.37,  145.06,  21090636',

     '144.73,  145.85,  144.38,  145.53,  19781836',

     '145.50,  148.49,  145.44,  147.77,  25199373',

     '147.97,  149.33,  147.33,  149.04,  20132061',

     '148.82,  150.90,  148.57,  149.56,  23793456',

     '150.48, 151.42,  149.95,  151.02,  20922969']

#fitting the data in. This is where is said there was a error ,but it
#is still consistent with the variables above
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

#tells it to predict
test = clf.predict([[9, 12, 17]])

#prints the prediction
print(test)
```

Then the error it gives me when I try to run it

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/kodecreer/Documents/PersonalDataProj.py", line 117, in 
>       clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 790, in fit
>       X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 236, in fit
>       "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
>   ValueError: Number of labels=44 does not match number of samples=45

I tried uninstalling the scikit then reinstall it again and refreshed the python compiler. I also tried searching all over stackoverflow and couldn't find it...

Answer :Input doesn't match output ,so that's why its doing that. Thank you Tomohiro Egawa for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error is happening due to "Number of labels=44 does not match number of samples=45"
Which means you X and Y length is different. Can you confirm the X and Y length?

Comment: yea it worked . Sorry I wasted your time. I am only started it a week ago ,so I am kind of a noob with this

Comment: No worries. every one start from a noob.